# Swift - After performing AVAssetExportSession, if I hit the home button and reopen the app, the video disappears from my AVPlayer and it goes black

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer, avassetexportsession

If I wait a few seconds and close/reopen the app (or scroll the video), the video eventually comes back. I am completely lost as to why the video just disappears and my `AVPlayer` goes black.

Has anyone encountered this and/or know of a fix?

Edit: I set up the AVPlayer inside an AVPlayerLayer like so: https://codeshare.io/vmBHX

Comment: is it in a scrollview?

Comment: Ok I just zeroed in on the problem. I am using  AVVideoCompositionCoreAnimationTool to apply overlays on my video. If I remove this, the problem goes away so for some reason using this causes the AVPlayerLayer to fail when the app enters the background.

Comment: @riverhawk same problem here, also using AVVideoCompositionCoreAnimationTool to apply overlays. Did you find the solution?

Comment: I have not, I submitted a bug report to Apple so I'm curious to see what they say. If you figure it out, could you post the answer here?

Comment: @riverhawk of course I will post it here dude. Please do the same :)

Comment: @riverhawk Can you please edit your question to reflect your first comment? The issue is not about AVAssetExportSession but about AVVideoCompositionCoreAnimationTool because if we remove it then it works fine..

Comment: I posted a question to reflect the real issue with AVVideoCompositionCoreAnimationTool http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39891353/swift-3-issue-with-avvideocompositioncoreanimationtool-to-add-watermark-on-vid

Comment: @riverhawk have you found a solution?

Comment: @Sam I haven't =( Was hoping it would be patched in an update...Apple also said my report was a duplicate of another persons report and I don't think it was resolved for them either..

Comment: @riverhawk Thanks for your answer. This is really annoying.. They also said my report was a duplicate but the issue has not been resolved yet..

Comment: @Sam Yah, I wish I could help you man. I'm probably going to ship my product regardless because it's on them not us. Hopefully a patch will fix it for us.

Comment: @Sam looks like they fixed it in the most recent patch!