# VideoTrack Transform with CALayers

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, transform, calayer

I'm creating Video by `AVMutableComposition`. There are number of videos tracks and I am adding transform transition between two video tracks with `AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction`.

**setOpacityRamp, setTransformRamp** (dissolve, wipe and push transition between videotracks).

**Problem is**

There is **textLayer or imagelayer (CALayer)** as scene in between Video tracks while creating the composition.

( Brief of the structure given below)

> --videoTrack--videotrack--emptytrack--videotrack--
>
> -----------------------------------textlayer---------------------

The transition transformation between **videotrack--emptytrack--videotrack--** is actually happening. At the topmost of the player there is CALayer, so the transition is not visible.

I'm syncing CALayer with video by `AVSynchronizedLayer` on local player and `AVVideoCompositionCoreAnimationTool` on export.

**1. Creating TextScene or imageScene Video by CALayer with emptyVideoTrack, is this correct way ?**

**2. Is any other way to create textScene, imageScene video with actual videotrack transition?**

Comment: This is due to a bug with AVVideoCompositionCoreAnimationTool please check this post and all related posts http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39891353/swift-3-issue-with-avvideocompositioncoreanimationtool-to-add-watermark-on-vid

Comment: Some have implemented workaround. However I was not able to fix this issue so I would be interested if you manage to find a solution please